# Websocket server using php for flutter app

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, websocket

I am trying to make a chat application using php and database as mysql.I know native php,how can i make a websocket server for chat application using php.Can anyone tell the process of making php websocket server for my flutter application.If it is not possible with native php how can I make?Suggest me the easiest php library for making the websocket [i want to make a server like this](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html).If it is possible with native php then how?